# How to capture a shipping address within a Stripe subscription Checkout?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, subscription

I am creating an online subscription service that will deliver goods to people's house. While I can accept their name, zipcode, and payment information, I am unable to get them to type in their address. Why is this the case?

This is the logic that takes customers from my website to the stripe checkout page.

```js
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js'

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_API_KEY)

export async function initiateCheckout({lineItems} = {}) {
  const stripe = await stripePromise
  await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: 'subscription',
    lineItems,
    successUrl: `${window.location.origin}?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/microgreens`,
  })
}
```

I get this error before I am redirected to the checkout page:

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: shipping_address_collection is not an accepted parameter.
```

Here is a screenshot of the checkout page:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you shared doesn't have anything related to the shipping address collection configuration, I assume you accidentally deducted it when you are copy/pasting the code. However, looking at the error message it looks like you try to set it like `shipping_address_collection: { ... }`. The correct parameter should be `shippingAddressCollection`. It is camel-case, not underscored.

For official docs, you can see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-shippingAddressCollection).

So, it should look like this:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_API_KEY);

export async function initiateCheckout({lineItems} = {}) {
  const stripe = await stripePromise;

  await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: 'subscription',
    shippingAddressCollection: {
      allowedCountries: [ ... ],
    },
    lineItems,
    successUrl: `${window.location.origin}?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/microgreens`,
  });
```